# How to bind Alt+Arrows to PageUp/PageDown?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I just tried it using `loadkeys` and this map file:

```
alt keycode 73 = Prior
string Prior = "\033[5~"
alt keycode 81 = Next
string Next = "\033[6~"
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have to use `loadkeys`?

Comment: Turns out loadkeys is for TTYs. We'll have to use xkbcomp also, I'm slowly digging it.

Comment: What about xbindkeys or xmodmap?

Comment: xbindkeys is excessive for this, xmodmap - yeah, could be :) I'm just working with a xkbcomp dump already.

Comment: But if you'll find a way with xbindkeys it would be ok too, I guess :)

Comment: I'll try and add an answer tomorrow :)

Answer (score 11):

Install `xbindkeys` and `xte`:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation
```

Next we need to find the key mappings for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>.

Run `xbindkeys -k` and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> plus whatever arrow key you want.  For <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> I get:

```
"NoCommand"
m:0x18 + c:111
Alt+Mod2 + Up
```

Now that we know what the bindings for our keys are we need to create the `.xbindkeys` configuration file.  Run:

```
touch .xbindkeysrc
gedit .xbindkeysrc
```

`touch` creates the file and `gedit` opens it.  Now add:

```
"xte 'key Page_Up'"
m:0x18 + c:111
Alt+Mod2 + Up
```

To the file and save it.  This will bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> to <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

The basic syntax for `xbindkeys` is:

```
"command to run (in quotes)"
keysym of key
```

Your complete file should look almost identical to this:

```
"xte 'key Page_Down'"
m:0x18 + c:116
Alt+Mod2 + Down  

"xte 'key Page_Up'"
m:0x18 + c:111
Alt+Mod2 + Up
```

Now add `xbindkeys` to "Startup Applications" to make it run when you boot your computer.
Click 'Add' and put `/usr/bin/xbindkeys` in the 'Command' field.

[image]

Click 'Add' again and reboot.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( Tried both `m:0x8 + c:111` (just Alt+Up) and `m:0x18 + c:111` and both in Unity and KDE.

Comment: @int_ua Did you get your bindings from `xbindkeys -k` or did you copy them from my post?  You should get your own from `xbindkeys -k`.

Comment: I tried both but now I've used it second time in Unity and it gives different result: `m:0x18 + c:64` Edit: no, the same. Had to kill another xbindkeys.

Comment: Does not work for me either. I tried to remap `Alt + Left` to `Home`.

Comment: @Rasmus That's odd. What is the contents of your `.xbindkeysrc`? (post it to paste.ubuntu.com so I can look).

Comment: @Seth Just to be clear, the upvote of your comment was to indicate gratitude and that I had uploaded :)

Comment: @Rasmus Ah, I'm not notified about upticks. You need to ping me (like you just did). What's the link to your paste?

Answer (score 1):

I read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts which helped me figure out the following. While the *xautomation* package that includes the `xte` tool might be used instead of `xvkbd` to emit the key codes I used `xvkbd` to do the same thing.

`sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xbindkeys-config xvkbd`

`xbindkeys --defaults > /home/your-user-name/.xbindkeysrc`

For some reason this added a binding for ctrl-f that I had to comment out. While perhaps a useful default example I need ctrl-f to find inside of web pages.

After figuring out the "keysims" of **Prior** for *PgUp* and **Next** for *PgDown* this wasn't too tough. Running and using `xbindkeys-config` resulted in the following entries in .xbindkeysrc for me.

```
#alt-up
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[Prior]""
    m:0x18 + c:111
    Alt+Mod2 + Up

#alt-down
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[Next]""
    m:0x18 + c:116
    Alt+Mod2 + Down
```

when using Ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin after creating the .xbindkeysrc file it was detected and the `xbindkeys` program was run automatically on my next login.

The same will work for ctrl.

```
#ctrl-up
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[Prior]""
    m:0x14 + c:111
    Ctrl+Mod2 + Up

#ctrl-down
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[Next]""
    m:0x14 + c:116
    Ctrl+Mod2 + Down
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
key   <UP> {
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [           Up,         KP_Prior ]
};
key <DOWN> { 
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [           Down,         KP_Next ]
};
key <LEFT> {
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [           Left,         KP_Home ]
};
key <RGHT> {
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [           Right,         KP_End ]
};
```

works only in some cases, posting **just for reference**, it's far from final solution.

P.S. `s/KP_//g` gives the same result.