# Ubuntu16.04/Gnome: How to swap AltGr and Ctrl right at keyboard?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

My keyboard key of <kbd>AltGr</kbd> does not work anymore. I want rebind the 
functionality of <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl_R</kbd>.

**What is the easiest way to rebind <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl_R</kbd>?**

**OS**: Ubuntu 16.04
**Desktop**: Gnome 3

I tried to use `xmodmap` with the following configuration:

```
!Swap right control and right alt
remove Control = Control_R
remove Mod1 = Alt_R
keycode 105 = Alt_R
keycode 108 = Control_R
add Control = Control_R
add Mod1 = Alt_R
```

But I always get the following error:

```
> xmodmap .Xmodmap
xmodmap:  .Xmodmap:3:  bad keysym in remove modifier list 'Alt_R', no corresponding keycodes
```

Moreover, the configuration of `xmodmap` is persistent throughout several
restarts.

---

Related Questions

- [How to bind Alt+Arrows to PageUp/PageDown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250791/how-to-bind-altarrows-to-pageup-pagedown)
- [remap right alt to behave as right ctrl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237564/remap-right-alt-to-behave-as-right-ctrl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functionality of <kbd>AltGr</kbd> for your keyboard layout is to access third level symbols of various keys, I suggest that you run this command:

```
setxkbmap -option lv3:switch
```

If it does what you want, you can make the change permanent by opening `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and changing the line

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:switch"
```